# Launching and uninstalling an application

Tags: java, blackberry

From the current application on a Blackberry, how do I (using Java):

- launch another application
- uninstall another application

Answer (score 0):

To invoke internal (native BlackBerry) applications you can use the [Invoke](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html) class, and to launch third-party applications you can use the [ApplicationManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html) class.  More details can be found on [this forum post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-run-application-from-another-application-based-on/m-p/292601).

To uninstall an application, see [this forum post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Uninstalling-application-programatically/m-p/27110#M1784).  I'm not sure if it would work to uninstall an application other than your own, but I can't think of a reason to do that anyway unless you're writing some sort of application management app.